Filtering SSH connections on a server behind NAT
I have a server where I can login through SSH. The server has a private IP address and sits behind a NAT. Another server with a public IP address receives SSH connections on a given port and forwards then to the private server using iptables. That works.
But the public-facing server receives hundreds of login attempts using random usernames. I would like to use fail2ban or similar to prevent attacks from specific IPs. The problem is that the public server does not know whether a login attempt was successful or not, only the private one does. But the private one does not see real IPs, as all connections appear to come from the public server IP.
Is there any workaround for this?


the private one does not see real IPs, as all connections appear to come from the public server IP.

This should not be happening in the first place. If the public server uses DNAT to redirect traffic via iptables, that only rewrites the destination address – not the source address.
I'm guessing you have an additional SNAT rule to rewrite the source address for some reason; e.g. maybe it was the easiest option to get the responses from the private server go the right way. If so, remove the SNAT rule and find another way to solve that routing issue – for example, set up "policy routing" rules on the private server so that it would route the outbound reply packets two different ways (iptables fwmarks can be useful here); or add a GRE or WG tunnel between the two servers if the packets need to take multiple hops from the private server to the public one.
Alternatively, set up rate limits on the public server – it should be possible to write an iptables rule that only allows X 'new' packets per second and adds heavy offenders to an ipset to block everything from them.

The problem is I have to use SNAT because the public server I use to forward ports is different from the router that the private server uses to access the internet. If I don't use SNAT, packets coming out of the private server will not be routed to the public server and will never reach the source connection.
Marks could be a solution, I guess. Do you happen to have an example of using them in a scenario like this?
